# Pipenv dependency error with PyYAML in Zappa

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies, pipenv, zappa

I am getting an error after updating zappa package on pip env

I have tried
`pipenv lock --clear` and then retry the install
and
`pipenv install --skip-lock`

following is a `pipenv graph --reverse` for PyYAML.

```sh
PyYAML==3.13
  - awscli==1.16.177 [requires: PyYAML>=3.10,<=3.13]
  - awsebcli==3.15.2 [requires: PyYAML>=3.10,<=3.13]
  - cfn-flip==1.2.0 [requires: PyYAML>=3.13b1]
    - troposphere==2.4.7 [requires: cfn-flip>=1.0.2]
      - zappa==0.48.2 [requires: troposphere>=1.9.0]
  - docker-compose==1.23.2 [requires: PyYAML>=3.10,<4]
    - awsebcli==3.15.2 [requires: docker-compose>=1.23.2,<1.24.0]
  - kappa==0.6.0 [requires: PyYAML>=3.11]
    - zappa==0.48.2 [requires: kappa==0.6.0]
  - zappa==0.48.2 [requires: PyYAML>=3.13]
```

and the error message is as following,

```sh
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pyyaml<4,<=3.13,<=5.1,>=3.10,>=3.11,>=3.13,>=4.1
Tried: 3.10, 3.10, 3.11, 3.11, 3.12, 3.12, 3.12, 3.12, 3.12, 3.12, 3.12, 3.12, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1
Skipped pre-versions: 3.13b1, 3.13b1, 3.13b1, 3.13b1, 3.13b1, 3.13b1, 3.13b1, 3.13b1, 3.13b1, 3.13b1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 3.13rc1, 4.2b1, 4.2b2, 4.2b4, 4.2b4, 4.2b4, 4.2b4, 4.2b4, 5.1b1, 5.1b3, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b5, 5.1b7
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.
```

I didn't try the following as I would want the package to be stable.
`pipenv lock --pre`

Comment: My guess is: the graph shows what is installed, but something in your Pipfile now is inconsistent and Pipenv can't come up with a correct solution.

Comment: Its Zappa that has problematic dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `awscli`, and `awsebcli` need `pyyaml<=3.13`, whereas `cfn-flip` (through `zappa`, through `zappa`) needs `pyyaml>3.13b1`. `pipenv install` is also skipping pre-releases, `pyyaml==3.131b` being one of them.

You could explicitly require a version of `troposphere` older than `2.4.7` such that `pyyaml<=3.13` is installed to solve this problem.

Comment: you are right. I changed the dependency and it worked.